# Raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!") while converting Save Numpy Array to CSV File

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset MSL_test.npy file , how can I convert them into csv format, I already saw previous thread on this but unable to solve the error

I tried to execute this code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame("Z:/ADwork2/python/PM/SMAP/SMAP_train.npy")
df.to_csv('Z:/ADwork2/python/PM/SMAP/SMAP.csv',index=False)
```

but got this error

File "C:\Users\user11\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 529, in **init**
raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!") ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: See [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html): `Parameters: 
data: ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame`. Not a string.

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the numpy file first by using [**`numpy.load`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

array = np.load(r'Z:/ADwork2/python/PM/SMAP/SMAP_train.npy')

df = pd.DataFrame(array)
df.to_csv(r'Z:/ADwork2/python/PM/SMAP/SMAP.csv',index=False)
```